# svchost.exe hogging all my internet

Tags: windows-10, svchost

I'm using windows 10 and I've a svchost.exe service that is taking 80% of my internet for several hours now. I'm suspecting windows update but when entering windows update in the GUI there seems to be now indication of windows downloading anything.

How can I determine what its doing?

Comment: if you use Task Manager, from the Details page, if you right click on the process, you can click on "go to service(s)". Or you can get the PID from the details page and find the PID in the services page.  Figuring out the service or services is the first step. You could also download Process Explorer, and you can then see the services hosted and which is using the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable win downloading any time and specify special hours for ur updates or do it manually. also in win 10, there is an option you can provide downloaded updates in your system for other people on the net. disable this option and check svchost.exe again

Comment: Have done that but still downloading. Seems like it was an update that was already ongoing. But next time I will try to google the PID and terminate it if its not crucial.

Comment: if you restart your computer, next time the download process will continue automatically?